# What packages can I update in OpenVZ contained guest?

Tags: debian, vps, openvz, upgrade

Recently I bought low cost (1$/m, 256 MiB) VPS based on OpenVZ virtualization. There are pre-built guest Debian 7.0.

I like stay with more recent Debian stable release - 8.0.

Is it safe to:

```
sed -i 's/wheezy/stable/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade        # actually I do that
                       # as package list has only userland soft
apt-get dist-upgrade   # <== but afraid this
```

taking in mind that we under OpenVZ container?

What packages is not allowed to replace in OpenVZ container? `libc`? `linux-image`?

**UPDATE** My `/etc/inittab` and `/boot/*` empty. Seems that I also restricted in config file modifications...

Comment: Give it a go. If it doesn't work you can reset it easily anyway.

Comment: Currently I exercises with my first VPS and it's ok to break installation. But I have theoretical interest that really bad may happen if replace `initrd`, `libc`, `linux-image`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [research of boot process of container OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31819284/173149) I investigate that OpenVZ doesn't use `grub`/`linux-image`/`initrd` from guest OS and do direct call to first that find among:

```
/sbin/init -z
/etc/init -z
/bin/init -z
```

in guest OS (after isolating, securing and mounting to guest). In order to stop it uses one of

```
halt
init 0
reboot
```

from guest OS.

So even you install kernel image or build own `initrd`, install `grub`/`lilo` in VE them are not used by boot process. Kernel modules are not loaded.

So it is safe to install any package, that doesn't break you `init` process and `ssh` link (keeping VE bootable). Some packages just don't work as some system calls restricted. You even may update `libc` if it is compatible with kernel v2.6.32 (OpenVZ kernel).